# What is wrong with my Package Body?? Oracle SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package, sqlplus

I'm new to oracle and have been working on a package body that is resulting in errors.

(for reference) My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(custname VARCHAR2(10),
account_no NUMBER(5),
cur_balance NUMBER(6)
)
/
```

My package is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE c_package AS 
   -- Adds a customer 
   PROCEDURE addCustomer(c_name  customers.custname%type, 
   c_account_no  customers.account_no%type, 
   c_cur_balance customers.cur_balance%type);

   -- Removes a customer 
   PROCEDURE delCustomer(c_account_no  customers.account_no%TYPE); 

   --Lists all customers 
   PROCEDURE listCustomer; 
  
END c_package; 
/
```

My package body is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY c_package AS
   PROCEDURE addCustomer(
   c_name       customers.custname%type, 
   c_account_no     customers.account_no%type, 
   c_cur_balance    customers.cur_balance%type)
   IS 
   BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO customers(custname,account_no,cur_balance) 
      VALUES(c_name, c_account_no, c_cur_balance); 
   END addCustomer;

   PROCEDURE delCustomer(c_account_no   customers.account_no%type)
   IS 
   BEGIN 
      DELETE FROM customers 
      WHERE account_no = c_account_no; 
   END delCustomer;

   PROCEDURE listCustomer IS 
   CURSOR c_customers is 
      SELECT  custname FROM customers; 
   TYPE c_list is TABLE OF customers.custname%type; 
   custname_list c_list := c_list(); 
   counter integer :=0; 
   BEGIN 
      FOR n IN c_customers LOOP 
      counter := counter +1; 
      custname_list.extend; 
      custname_list(counter) := n.custname; 
      dbms_output.put_line('Customer(' ||counter|| ')'||custname_list(counter)); 
      END LOOP; 
   END listCustomer;
END c_package; 
/
```

The error i keep getting is:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/19     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp
         interval date binary national character nchar
         The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.


4/25     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp
         interval date binary national character nchar
         The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.


5/26     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp
         interval date binary national character nchar
         The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------


12/47    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the
         following:
         in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp
         interval date binary national character nchar
         The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "." to continue.
```

I'm not sure what it is, I think it may be a typo somewhere, but I don't know which one, as i have said, I'm new to oracle sqlplus and still figuring it out, some help would be truly appreciated, thankyou :)

Comment: Do you get complete time error ? Because I just executed the code in fiddle and it all compiled without any issue.

Comment: Every time i execute the code in oracle sqlplus i get this error: Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

Comment: Not sure what is going on. "Works on my machine". You might have some definitions in your login.sql or glogin.sql scripts. What does 'define' say? https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables

Comment: Works fine for me too. Strangely, line 3 column 19 isn't the symbol `.`. The first dot is at column 26, so not sure what could be going on. All the errors seem to refer to incorrectly formed parameters. I can only reproduce the error by removing the word `customers`.

Comment: By the way, not related but normally if we are prefixing parameters, we use `p_` (for 'parameter') or `in_`/`out_` (to indicate the parameter mode). I have sometimes seen `a_` (for 'argument', I suppose), or else some camelCase convention such as `custName`. `c_` normally indicates a constant or cursor.

Comment: @evey4578 can you drop all those object then run and post here full sqlplus output of all those ddl commands with enabled `set echo on feed on sqlblank on;` Then check exact package text in user_source